# How to process the GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetail and GetServiceLastAccessedDetail apis of AWS using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pymongo, boto3

I have been using the boto library to integrate with the AWS apis. Here I am facing an issue in order to get the **GetServiceLastAccessedDetail** report. For this I need to process the **GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetail**  .

The documentation says to use the ARN with GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetail to process. My question here is:

what is the exact/ valid syntax to process this reports using python?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get confused on entering the keyword. While using the boto3, you need to add the ARN along with the string.

In case for IAM:

Syntax:

Connect with your client, then.

```
response_generate = client.generate_service_last_accessed_details(Arn='arn:aws:iam::youridgoeshere:user/Name')
response = client.get_service_last_accessed_details(JobId=response_generate["JobId"])
```

From the response you will get the report in JSON format.